# Can I define multiple names for a theorem?

Tags: isabelle

Suppose I have a theorem:

```
theorem non_ASCII_thm_name:
  "True"
  by simp
```

I want to define an ASCII name for `non_ASCII_thm_name` with something like the `notation` command. For example, like this:

```
notation non_ASCII_thm_name ("ASCII_thm_name")
```

The Isar commands `notation` and `abbreviation` can only be used with constants. Is there an Isar command that allows me to to this?

Preferably, all I want my Isar command to provide is a synonym. For example, if I use `sledgehammer`, it would be preferable that there exist only one theorem, `non_ASCII_thm_name`, so that `sledgehammer` is not using an additional fact `ASCII_thm_name`.

Comment: `theorems ASCII_thm_name = non_ASCII_thm_name` will let you _write_ an ASCII name (albeit it won't be output by tools such as `find_theorems`). Is this sufficient?

Comment: Thanks. That's one answer, and looks like something you should turn into an answer. It's allowing me to use `ASCII_thm_name` in place of `non_ASCII_thm_name`. What I'm trying to determine now is whether it's a simple synonym. If it's not a simple synonym, then it would be preferable to find a solution which gives me a simple synonym, as explained by my addition of the last paragraph to the question.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds pedantic, but what practical difference do you see between a synonym and a duplicate of the original theorem under a new name?

Comment: Performance, with Sledgehammer in particular. If I have a thousand theorems, with two names for each theorem, and the extra name creates a duplicate theorem, rather than a synonym, then potentially, 2000 facts will be fed to Sledgehammer rather than 1000 facts. I can't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation points yet. It's a good answer even if it doesn't provide a simple synonym.

Comment: Sledgehammer appears to remove duplicate theorems prior to feeding them to an ATP (see `fun uniquify`, called by `fun nearly_all_facts` in `sledgehammer_fact.ML`), meaning there will be a minimal impact of having duplicate theorems defined using `theorems`.

Comment: I looked at that; I'll take your word. I only need "effectively a synonym". But it seems bad style to create duplicate facts rather than use notation. It's not of ultimate importance if it doesn't affect performance much, but I'll be having 2 names for each theorem. For completeness, from isar-ref, `theorems` is the same as `lemmas`: _lemmas a = b1 ... bn for x1 ... xm evaluates given facts (with attributes) in the current context, which may be augmented by local variables. Results are standardized before being stored, i.e. schematic variables are renamed to enforce index 0 uniformly._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial solution is to use the command:

```
lemmas ASCII_thm_name = non_ASCII_thm_name
```

This will define a new theorem called `ASCII_thm_name` which will be the same as `non_ASCII_thm_name`.

There is unfortunately no guarantee that tools such as `find_theorems` will use your new name, but will instead use their own heuristics for determining which is the "best" name to output back to the user.

An alternative synonym for `lemmas` is `theorems`, though the former is considered to be the more standard approach.

Comment: You can tell find_theorems to give you all names by providing the option (with_dups), i.e. "find_theorems (with_dups) rest_of_query"

Comment: A bibliography entry has been added to a document crediting this answer to the David G. that has recently been active on the Isabelle mailing lists. If this is not desired, then @davidg should protest.

Comment: Most of the Isabelle distribution seems to prefer `lemmas` over `theorems`; much like `lemma` is preferred over `theorem`. Their semantics are the same, though.

Comment: @GBa: That's me, though I suspect referencing me or this post is probably overkill. :)

Comment: @davidg, naw, it's my rule. If I ask a question and get an answer in a public forum, then I add a bibliography entry. It tells me where I got the answer, in case I need to look at it again.