# How to get a typedef type to inherit operators from its mother type for type classes

Tags: isabelle

**Post Answer Follow Up Question**

Brian provided an answer with a suggested solution being to use lifting and transfer. However, I can't find enough tutorial information on lifting and transfer to know how to tweak his answer to finish off what I would need to do.

Here, I work in the dark, and use the answer given as a plug'n'play template to ask this follow up question.

The command in my initial code, `typedef trivAlg = "{x::sT. x = emS}"` gives me a new type that is a subset of the mother type `sT`.

I have my membership operator `consts inP :: "sT => sT => bool"`, and so in my naive view of lifting and transfer, since my `monoid_add` 0 has been defined as being the constant `emS::sT`, and I can make this statement, `(emS::sT) inP emS`, I would want to do something like this:

```
theorem "~((0::trivAlg) inP 0)"
```

So, I try to use lifting to get my operator `inP` to work with type `trivAlg` like this:

```
lift_definition inP_trivAlg :: "trivAlg => trivAlg => bool"
  is "% x y. (x inP y)" 
  by simp

theorem "~((0::trivAlg) inP 0)"

theorem "(emS::trivAlg) = emS"
```

However, I get type clashes with my use of `theorem` because my use of type `sT` and `trivAlg` aren't compatible.

If the answer can be added to to show me how to get my `inP` to work with type `trivAlg` I would appreciate it. Or, maybe I'm way off the mark.

**Preliminaries to the (Original) Question**

I have my type `sT`, which represents "everything is a set". So far, all my constants and operators have been defined with the single type `sT`. For example, my empty set, membership operator, and union operator are defined something like this:

```
consts emS :: "sT"
consts inP :: "sT => sT => bool"
consts geU :: "sT => sT"
```

I'm now doing some early investigating into whether I can tie my `sT` into the generalized groups in [Groups.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Groups.html).

From the [HOL document](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/document.pdf), I'm trying to get examples from sections 4.2, 4.3, and 4.4 of Groups, and 15.2 and 15.3 of Nat.

Here, I'm almost to my question, but I don't know enough to know whether I'm asking an intelligent question. What I think I know is that the solution may be with locales, sublocales, and interpretations only rather than with type classes.

I've been looking a little at [locales.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/locales.pdf) and [classes.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/classes.pdf), and so I know that locales and classes are intertwined. I've also been looking at [IsarMathLib](http://slawekk.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/isarmathlib-1-8-0-released/) to see how locales, sublocales, and interpretations are being used there.

**The Question**

My question is, with my trivial algebraic structure below, `trivAlg`, which is a new type defined with `typedef`, how can I set things up with type classes so that I can use my constants, such as `emS`, `inP`, and `geU` listed above, with elements of type `trivAlg`?

After I list the code below, I ask some questions about specific lines of code in [Groups.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Groups.html).

**The Code**

```
typedef trivAlg = "{x::sT. x = emS}"
  by auto

instantiation trivAlg :: zero
begin
definition trivAlg_zero:
  "0 = Abs_trivAlg emS"
instance ..
end

instantiation trivAlg :: monoid_add
begin
definition plus_trivAlg:
  "m + n = (Abs_trivAlg emS)" 
instance proof
  fix n m q :: trivAlg
  show "(n + m) + q = n + (m + q)"
    by(metis plus_trivAlg)
  show "0 + n = n"
    apply(induct n) apply(auto)
    by(metis plus_trivAlg)
  show "n + 0  = n"
    apply(induct n) apply(auto)
    by(metis plus_trivAlg)
qed
end

theorem
  "((n::trivAlg) + m) + q = n + (m + q)"
  by(metis plus_trivAlg)

theorem
  "((0::trivAlg) + 0) = 0"
  by(metis monoid_add_class.add.left_neutral)
```

**A Subsequent Question about Groups.thy**

On lines 151 to 155 in Groups.thy, there is the following code:

```
class semigroup_add = plus +
  assumes add_assoc [algebra_simps, field_simps]: "(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)"

sublocale semigroup_add < add!: semigroup plus proof
qed (fact add_assoc)
```

There's no one document to teach me how to use classes, locales, sublocales, and interpretations, so I don't know exactly what this tells me.

If I want to use the `semigroup_add` that's in Groups.thy, do I have the choice of using it either as a type class or a locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the corresponding operations on type `trivAlg`, probably the easiest way is to use Isabelle's Lifting package; you can then use the Transfer package to prove the class instances. Here is an example:

```
typedef trivAlg = "{x::sT. x = emS}"
  by auto

setup_lifting type_definition_trivAlg

instantiation trivAlg :: zero
begin
lift_definition zero_trivAlg :: "trivAlg" is "emS" .
instance ..
end

instantiation trivAlg :: monoid_add
begin
lift_definition plus_trivAlg :: "trivAlg => trivAlg => trivAlg"
  is "% x y. emS"
by simp

instance proof
  fix n m q :: trivAlg
  show "(n + m) + q = n + (m + q)"
    by transfer simp
  show "0 + n = n"
    by transfer simp
  show "n + 0  = n"
    by transfer simp
qed
end
```

Comment: The lifting and transfer looks promising, since I like the idea of `typedef` making it easy to get new subsets of my type `sT`. I left a follow up question, if you have time to answer it. I'll also start searching for information on how to use lifting and transfer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple things kill me if I don't know what the syntax means, and much of learning Isabelle/HOL is "stare at multiple examples for long periods of time", which is not to say there's not a lot of documentation for Isabelle relative to other proof assistants.

Here I finish off the question I had on how to actually use what Brian gave me.

My `inP` is actually binary notation for the function `in_P :: sT => sT => bool`, which is what I want to lift over to type `trivAlg`, though I'm not sure I just now used the term "lift" correctly.

From the [Isabelle user's list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2013-January/msg00134.html), I found an example showing the lifting of the HOL `union` operator. Similarly, I lift my `in_P` like this:

```
lift_definition in_P_trivAlg :: "trivAlg => trivAlg => bool"
  is "in_P :: sT => sT => bool" 
  by simp
```

In my previous trial and error attempts, I had been using my `inP`, which is only notation, and it hadn't sunk in that `lift_definition` is introducing a brand new function. Those those things finally occurred to me, and instead of "trial and error", I got "trial and success" by using the function `in_P_trivAlg` intelligently like this:

```
theorem "~(in_P_trivAlg 0 0)"
  by(metis 
    Ax_em 
    in_P_trivAlg.rep_eq 
    zero_trivAlg.rep_eq)
```

This says that the empty set doesn't contain itself. That's good, and tells me I'm on the right track, considering that 0 has been defined to be `emS`, which is defined, with the axiom `Ax_em`, to contain no elements .

I now need to figure out how to overload my membership operator notation `\<in>\<^isub>\iota>`. Overloading notation hasn't been important until now, since I've had a need to *not* overload most standard notation, like `\<in>`.

It looks like I'll have a need to rename theorems, such as `in_P_trivAlg.rep_eq`, and I just got the answer for that from ["Can I define multiple names for a theorem?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823938/can-i-define-multiple-names-for-a-theorem).

From [RealVector.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/RealVector.html), I now see that there's a lot of renaming using the `lemmas` command, such as

```
text {* Recover original theorem names *}

lemmas scaleR_left_commute = real_vector.scale_left_commute
lemmas scaleR_zero_left = real_vector.scale_zero_left
...
```

The purpose of that code would have meant nothing to me if it wasn't for the Stackoveflow answer I just provided a link to.