# Trying to Treat Type Classes and Sub-types Like Sets and Subsets

Tags: types, typeclass, set, isabelle

This question is related to my previous SO question about 
[type classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889860). I ask this question to set up a future question about locales. I don't think type classes will work for what I'm trying to do, but how type classes work have given me ideas about what I want out of locales.

Below, when I use the braces notation `{0,0}`, it doesn't represent the normal HOL braces, and `0` represents the empty set.

### Some files if you want them

- [A_i130424a.thy](http://github.com/gc44/arc/blob/master/1300/i130424a__cannot_use_typedef_for_semigroup/dist/A_i130424a.thy) - ASCII friendly THY.
- [i130424a.thy](http://github.com/gc44/arc/blob/master/1300/i130424a__cannot_use_typedef_for_semigroup/dist/i130424a.thy) - non-ASCII friendly THY.
- [i130424a_DOC.pdf](http://gc44.github.io/viz/arc_1300/i130424a__cannot_use_typedef_for_semigroup/i130424a_DOC.pdf) - PDF showing line numbers.
- [MFZ_DOC.pdf](http://gc44.github.io/viz/arc_1300/i130424aMFZ/MFZ_DOC.pdf) - Main project this is related to.
- [GitHub folder for this question](http://github.com/gc44/arc/tree/master/1300/i130424a__cannot_use_typedef_for_semigroup/dist) and [MFZ GitHub](http://github.com/gc44/arc/tree/master/1300/i130424aMFZ/dist) folder.

### Pre-question talk

I describe what I'm doing in the THY (which I include at the bottom), and then I basically ask, "Is there something I can do here to fix this so that I can use type classes?"

As in the SO question linked to above, I'm trying to tie into [Groups.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Groups.html) `semigroup_add`. What I do is create a subtype of my type `sT` using `typedef`, and I then try to lift some of my essential function constants and operators into the new type, such as my union operator `geU`, my empty set `emS`, my unordered pair sets `paS`, and my membership predicate `inP`.

This doesn't work because I'm trying to treat the new type like a subset. In particular, my new type is supposed to represent the set `{ {0,0} }`, which is intended to be part of the trivial semigroup, a semigroup with only one element.

The problem is that the unordered pair axiom states that if set `x` exists, then set `(paS x x)` exists, and the union axiom states that if set `x` exists, then set `(geU x)` exists. So, when I try to lift my union operator into my new type, the prover magically knows I need to prove `(geU{0,0} = {0,0})`, which is not true, but there's only one element `{0,0}` in my new type, so it would have to be that way.

### Question

Can I fix this? In my mind, I'm comparing sets and subsets with types and sub-types, where I know they're not the same. Call my main type `sT` and my subtype `subT`. What I need is for all my operators that have been defined with type `sT`, types such as `sT => sT`, to work for type `subT` when `subT` is being treated as type `sT`. The new operators and constants that have been defined using type `subT`, such as a function of type `subT => subT`, that would somehow work out like things are magically supposed to work with these things.

### Post question talk

Here, I point out what's happening by line number in the THY. The line numbers will show up in the PDF and on the GitHub site.

In lines 21 to 71 there are four sections where I combined related constants, notation, and an axiom.

1. Type `sT`, membership predicate `inP/PIn`, and equality axiom (21 to 33).
2. Empty set `emS/SEm` and empty set axiom (37 to 45).
3. Unordered pair constant `paS/SPa` and unordered pair axiom (49 to 58).
4. Union constant `geU/UGe` and union axiom (62 to 71).

Starting at line 75 is where I create a new type with `typedef` and then instantiate it as type class `semigroup_add`.

There are no problems until I try to lift my unordered pair function `{.x,y.}`, line 108, and my union function `(geU x)`, line 114.

Below the Isar commands, I show the output that's telling me I need to prove that certain sets are equal to `{0,0}`, a fact that cannot be proved.

Here is the ASCII friendly source, where I've deleted some comments and lines from the THY linked to above:

```
theory A_i130424a
imports Complex_Main 
begin  

--"AXIOM (sT type, inP predicate, and the equality axiom)"
typedecl sT ("sT")

consts PIn :: "sT => sT => bool"

notation
  PIn  ("in'_P") and
  PIn  (infix "inP" 51) and
  PIn  (infix "inP" 51)

axiomatization where
  Ax_x: "(! x. x inP r <-> x inP s) <-> (r = s)"
--"[END]"



--"AXIOM (emS and the empty set axiom)"
consts SEm :: "sT" ("emS")

notation (input)
  SEm ("emS")

axiomatization where
  Ax_em [simp]: "(x niP emS)"
--"[END]"



--"AXIOM (paS and the axiom of unordered pairs)"
consts SPa :: "sT => sT => sT"

notation
  SPa ("paS") and
  SPa ("({.(_),(_).})")

axiomatization  where
  Ax_pa [simp]: "(x inP {.r,s.}) <-> (x = r | x = s)"
--"[END]"



--"AXIOM (geU and the axiom of unions)"
consts UGe :: "sT => sT"

notation
  UGe ("geU") and
  UGe ("geU")

axiomatization where
  Ax_un: "x inP geU r = (? u. x inP u & u inP r)"
--"[END]"



--"EXAMPLE (A typedef type cannot be treated as a set of type sT)"
typedef tdLift = "{x::sT. x = {.emS,emS.}}"
  by(simp)

setup_lifting type_definition_tdLift

instantiation tdLift :: semigroup_add
begin
  lift_definition plus_tdLift:: "tdLift => tdLift => tdLift"
    is "% x y. {.emS,emS.}" by(simp)
  instance
  proof
    fix n m q :: tdLift
    show "(n + m) + q = n + (m + q)"
    by(transfer,simp)
  qed
end

theorem
  "((n::tdLift) + m) + q = n + (m + q)"
  by(transfer,simp)

class tdClass =
  fixes emSc :: "'a"                 ("emSk")
  fixes inPc :: "'a => 'a => bool"   (infix "∈k" 51)
  fixes paSc :: "'a => 'a => 'a"     ("({.(_),(_).}k)")
  fixes geUc :: "'a => 'a"           ("⋃k")

instantiation tdLift :: tdClass
begin
  lift_definition inPc_tdLift:: "tdLift => tdLift => bool"
    is "% x y. x inP y" 
    by(simp)
  lift_definition paSc_tdLift:: "tdLift => tdLift => tdLift"
    is "% x y. {.x,y.}"
    --"OUTPUT: 1. (!! (sT1 sT2). ([|(sT1 = emS); (sT2 = emS)|] ==> ({.sT1,sT2.} = emS)))"
    apply(auto)
    --"OUTPUT: 1. ({.emS.} = emS)"
    oops
  lift_definition geUc_tdLift:: "tdLift => tdLift"
    is "% x. geU x"
    --"OUTPUT: 1. (!! sT. ((sT = {.emS,emS.}) ==> ((geU  sT) = {.emS,emS.})))"
    apply(auto)
    --"OUTPUT: 1. ((geU  {.emS,emS.}) = {.emS,emS.})"
    oops  
  lift_definition emSc_tdLift:: "tdLift"
    is "emS" 
    --"OUTPUT: 
       exception THM 1 raised (line 333 of drule.ML):
       RSN: no unifiers
       (?t = ?t) [name HOL.refl]
       ((emS = {.emS,emS.}) ==> (Lifting.invariant (% x. (x = {.emS,emS.})) emS emS))"
    oops
  instance ..
end
--"[END]"


end
```

Answer (score 1):

I partially answer my question, and part of the reason is to refer to this when I ask a question about Isar subtypes. By all appearances, my question and answer here is related to subtypes.

As to whether I can fix the problem with type classes that I described, I don't know about that.

(UPDATE: The likely solution for my use of type classes will be a combination of ideas, part of the solution being type coercion, as explained in the answer to my SO question: [What is an Isabelle/HOL subtype? What Isar commands produce subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231071)

If using the locales in Groups.thy is the way to go for me, then the corresponding type classes to those locales will probably also work. I can instantiate a class such as `semigroup_add`, use `lift_definition` to define the `plus` operator, and even lift my operators that return a `bool` into the type. The operators that can't be lifted into the new type are somewhat nonsensical in the context of the new type anyway, wherein type coercion can come into play to make sense of them for things like unions of sets. [The devil is in the details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_is_in_the_details).)

With what I said I want out of types and subtypes, I figured out I do get a form of that with `typedef`, the form being the functions `Rep` and `Abs`, which I have been working with a little.

As described in [isar-ref.pdf pg. 242](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/isar-ref.pdf),

> For typedef t = A the newly introduced type t is accompanied by a pair of morphisms to relate it to the representing set over the old type. By default, the injection from type to set is called Rep t and its inverse Abs t...

Below, I use `Rep` and `Abs` in a small example to demonstrate that I can relate my main type, `sT`, with the new type I define with `typedef`, which is type `tsA`.

I don't think type classes are of ultimate importance. There are two main things I'm exploring,

1. whether I can tie into the locales of Groups.thy,
2. where that is more generally about using types to restrict the domain and co-domain of the binary operators of my semigroups, groups, etc.

For example, in Groups.thy, there is

```
locale semigroup =
  fixes f :: "'a => 'a => 'a" (infixl "*" 70)
  assumes assoc [ac_simps]: "a * b * c = a * (b * c)"
```

If I don't use subtypes, I think I'll have to do something like this, where `inP` is my `\<in>` (I'm just starting with locales):

```
locale sgA =
  fixes G :: sT
  fixes f :: "sT => sT => sT" (infixl "*" 70)
  assumes closed:
    "(a inP G) & (b inP G) --> (a * b) inP G"
  assumes assoc:
    "(a inP G) & (b inP G) & (c inP G) --> (a * b) * c = a * (b * c)"
```

Part of the answer in being able to use `Groups.semigroup` could be the use of `Rep` and `Abs`; I use the operator of type `tsA => tsA => tsA` on type `tsA`, but when the elements of type `tsA` need to be treated as elements of type `sT`, then I use `Rep` on them to map them to type `sT`.

I haven't thought all this out or experimented enough to know what will work best, but I gave this partial answer to try and explain more of what I have in my mind. There might be someone else out there with some good information to add.

The subtypes approach may not be all upside, as shown below by the last two `theorem` commands in the example code. The left-hand side of the implications are necessary because I'm not exploiting the power of types, similar to `closed` and `assoc` above in `locale sgA`. However, in spite of that, it's no problem for my `simp` rules, whereas, the theorems that are using `Rep` and `Abs` are requiring `metis` for the proofs, and it might require a lot of ugly overhead to get things working smoother.

Below I include the file [A_iSemigroup_xp.thy](http://github.com/gc44/arc/tree/master/1300/i130424aMFZ/dist/A_iSemigroup_xp.thy). This is an ASCII version of [iSemigroup_xp.thy](http://github.com/gc44/arc/tree/master/1300/i130424aMFZ/dist/iSemigroup_xp.thy). These require the import of [MFZ.thy](http://github.com/gc44/arc/tree/master/1300/i130424aMFZ/dist/MFZ.thy), where these 3 files are in this [GitHub folder](http://github.com/gc44/arc/tree/master/1300/i130424aMFZ/dist).

```
theory A_iSemigroup_xp
imports MFZ
begin
--"[END]"

--"EXAMPLE (Possible subtype for a trivial semigroup)"
typedef tsA = "{x::sT. x = emS}"
  by(simp)

theorem "(Rep_tsA x) inP {.Rep_tsA x.}"
  by(metis 
    SSi_exists)

theorem "! x::tsA. x = (Abs_tsA emS)"
  by(metis (lifting, full_types) 
    Abs_tsA_cases 
    mem_Collect_eq)

theorem "! x. x inP {.emS.} --> x = emS"
  by(simp)

theorem "! x. x inP {.z inP {.emS.} ¦ z = emS.} --> x = emS"
  by(simp)
--"[END]"

--"ISAR (Theory end)"
end
```