# How to define Subtypes in Isabelle and what they mean?

Tags: isabelle, subtyping, isar

The question regarding subtyping in Isabelle is very lengthy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206310/trying-to-treat-type-classes-and-sub-types-like-sets-and-subsets). So my simple question is that how I can define type B to be a subtype of A if I define A as below:

```
typedecl A
```

By doing this I would like to  make all operations and relations defined over A (they are not printed here) accessible to elements of type B.

A bit more complex example is to define B and C to be subtype of A such that B and C are disjoint, and every element of A is either of type B or of type C.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isabelle does not have subtypes, although some aspects of subtyping can be emulated as explained [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231071/). If you want to use the same operation on different types, you may want to look into Isabelle's type classes.

Comment: thanks, Is there any theorem prover based on a logic which support subtyping that I can use?